# search in tries in java

Tags: java, dictionary, trie

hi i have a project that i need to implement a dictionary by tries ... but now i can't implement search method .... my code is here

```
public class TriesNode {
String value;
ArrayList<TriesNode> children = new ArrayList<TriesNode>();


String findNode(TriesNode root , String key ){
    for (int i=0 ; i<key.length() ; ++i){
        char temp= key.charAt(i);
        if ( !(root.children.equals(temp)))
            return null;
        else
            root = root.children.value.equals(temp);
    }
}
```

in this code i have error in else statement!!!!
i want to replace the root by one of the children that it's value is similar to the first character of key(temp) but i can't do this in "else statement"  ... and why i can't access to the value of children??

Answer (score 0):

Ok, root is TriesNode type, but root.children is not the same type, that's the problem. You can't assign values from different types. You must declare a variable of root.children type and then assign that value. To assign directly the value of root.children to root you must do:

```
root.Add(root.children)
```

more or less...

Comment: i want to replace root by a children that have correct value but when i write " children.value" i can't access too value . what should i do?

Comment: you got an arraylist so you will have to pick one of them children.get(i) // here i is the location you want to get

Answer (score 0):

root = root.children.value.equals(temp) doesnt assign root.child to root rather it assigned true or false to root because your checking if it equals temp or not.

also java doesnt allow you to have if statement that returns value of different types from an if statemen.

this will return the final root in the chain, is that the value your looking for ?

try

```
        TriesNode findFinalRoot(TriesNode root, String key){
                      if(key.length() == 0 )
              return root;
        for(int x = 0 ; x <root.children.lenth(); x++)

          if (key.charAt(0) == root.children.get(x).charAt(0)){
             findFinalRoot(root,key.subString(1)); // here you loss first character       
}
```

Comment: i try to check if the the first character of key is the value of one of the children then replace the root by this child and then compare the second character of key by the children of new root .... 
 i have this code in python but i cant convert it to java 
"def find(node, key):
    for char in key:
        if char not in node.children:
            return None
        else:
            node = node.children[char]
    return node.value"

Comment: ok what you need to do is go through the whole array of the children one by one and check if the value is the same. I will change my answer to reflect what I have here

Comment: the root.children.lenth() isn't define for array List is any way  too get the length of the arraylist? or i should define children as a list?